# Error base64 encoding when testing upload image in django restful framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, base64

I'm writing unit tests trying to upload images and base64 encode it. But the encoding is different from expected.

This is my tests.py

```
    with open('tests/image.jpg', 'rb') as image:
        r = self.client.post('/images', {'image': image}, format='multipart')
```

This is my views.py

```
def post(self, request):
    image = request.FILES['image']
    base64_str = base64.b64encode(image.read()).decode('utf-8')
```

The base64_str turns out to be like `7f7NCd0Aw29mVx......`

Doing in a python script

```
with open('tests/image.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    print(base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8'))
```

The output is `/9j/4AAQSk......`

I suppose there is something wrong with the encoding. So what's the problem?

Comment: Check the request transfer encoding, content type, etc. It could be that the image is already b64 encoded within the request

Answer (score 0):

You sure you didn't just use encode, instead of decode in base64.b64encode?
After you encode you can decode with b64decode
I think it should be:

```
with open('tests/image.jpg', 'rb') as f:
     encoded_photo = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8'))
     decoded_photo = base64.b64decode(f.read()).decode('utf-8'))
```